# How do I get \sanssum and \sansprod with a sans serif typeface?

Tags: math-operators

How do I get `\sanssum` and `\sansprod` with a **sans serif** typeface denoting different meaning from `\sum` and `\prod` with a serif typeface? Hope them

1. act similarly to `\sum` and `\prod` as large orperators;
2. have the same structure and proportion as `\sum` and `\prod`;
3. have the same line weight (may be greater, but should be suitable since `\sum` and `\sanssum` will occur in the same place, otherwise it will lead to *visual conflicts*) and round caps for line beginning and ending as `\bigcap` and `\bigcup`.
   [image]
   So far as I know, `\varsum` and `\varprod` with a sans serif typeface could be found in the `fdsymbol` package as follows,
   [image]
   but they don't satisfy condition 2 and 3 as above. *Any help is welcome!*

Comment: @egreg I think you may be familiar with such creations.

Comment: There are few sans math fonts but none (at least none of the ones I know) has rounded caps.

Comment: I know of no sans serif font providing large symbols with round caps.

Comment: Your readers will be ungrateful

Comment: @egreg ...... Hope this be useful for somebody who needs it. By the way, I think such operators should be added in the basic files of LaTex as unicodes. There are many such useful symbols created in TSE.

Comment: @M.Logic -- Can you tell us what is the difference in meaning between the sans and the "usual" symbols?  Is it because you are setting all your math in sans serif?  I have never seen such forms in contrast to the "usual" ones.  (I was the person responsible for adding several thousand math/technical symbols to Unicode, compiled from requests from established scientific publishers, who requested only what they needed based on material in their books and journals.)

Comment: @barbara beeton There are three kinds of sum in my book about mathematical logic: `\sum` is used to be the sum of indexed family (for which some others may call disjoint union instead, in symbols `\biguplus`) which is corresponding to the product of indexed family, `\sanssum` (for which I even want to use a left-reversed `\sum` instead) is used to be the sum of infinitely many cardinals, and `\bigoplus` is used to be the sum of lots of first order structures.

Comment: @M.Logic - Thank you.  Have you seen any of these variants in a formally published document?  (That is, not as a preprint, a self-published document, or a source posted on arXiv, but under the imprint of a "recognized" publisher.)  If so, that qualifies to be considered for addition by Unicode; inclusion in fonts should follow Unicode acceptance.

Comment: Unicode's rules have been adopted to assure that characters are "accepted".  In the case of new math symbols that can happen quickly or may not happen at all.  One might wish the situation were more like that accorded to emoji, but sadly, there are fewer mathematicians than users of "smart phones".

Comment: @barbara beeton In fact not, but I think such new symbols could be created only if they are useful and beautiful.

Comment: @barbara beeton Then it may be better to define such symbols in ams packages.

Comment: Then this is your challenge: Create new symbols with care, define them well, use them in papers that are accepted by and published in journals with good reputations, then submit them to Unicode.  AMS has stated that there will be no changes to their font packages; the STIX project still exists, but conditions for acceptance there are very similar to those for Unicode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a solution with `pict2e`. Of course one can change the parameters at will.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}% for \slimits@ and scalable fraction rule width
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\sanssum}{\DOTSB\mathop{\mathpalette{\sans@op\sum{0.9}}\sans@sum}\slimits@}
\newcommand*{\sansprod}{\DOTSB\mathop{\mathpalette{\sans@op\prod{0.8}}\sans@prod}\slimits@}

\newcommand*{\sans@op}[4]{%
   \sbox0{\m@th$\m@th#3#1$}%
   \unitlength\ht0
   \advance\unitlength\dp0
   \vcenter{%
      \hbox{%
         \begin{picture}(#2,1)
            \linethickness{%
               \ifx#3\displaystyle2\fontdimen8\textfont\else
               \ifx#3\textstyle1.7\fontdimen8\textfont\else
               \ifx#3\scriptstyle1.6\fontdimen8\scriptfont\else
               1.6\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3}
            \roundcap
            \roundjoin
            #4
         \end{picture}%
      }%
   }%
}

\newcommand*{\sans@sum}{%
   \polyline(0.83,0.07)(0.08,0.07)(0.45,0.5)(0.08,0.93)(0.83,0.93)%
}
\newcommand*{\sans@prod}{%
   \put(0.05,0.93){\line(1,0){0.7}}%
   \put(0.19,0.07){\line(0,1){0.86}}%
   \put(0.61,0.07){\line(0,1){0.86}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
\begin{gather*}
                   \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \bigcup \sanssum_{i=1}^n a_i \\
\textstyle         \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \bigcup \sanssum_{i=1}^n a_i \\
\scriptstyle       \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \bigcup \sanssum_{i=1}^n a_i \\
\scriptscriptstyle \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \bigcup \sanssum_{i=1}^n a_i
\end{gather*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
\begin{gather*}
                   \prod_{i=1}^n a_i \bigcup \sansprod_{i=1}^n a_i \\
\textstyle         \prod_{i=1}^n a_i \bigcup \sansprod_{i=1}^n a_i \\
\scriptstyle       \prod_{i=1}^n a_i \bigcup \sansprod_{i=1}^n a_i \\
\scriptscriptstyle \prod_{i=1}^n a_i \bigcup \sansprod_{i=1}^n a_i
\end{gather*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @M.Logic I'm not sure what you mean but don't trust screenshots too much. I' ve got `okular` on a fairly old computer, so rendering issues occur quite often.

Comment: I improved some parameters of \sans@sum and \sans@prod and updated the picture

Comment: I tried to use your definition within a `\hl{}` from soul package, such as `\hl{$\sanssum_{i=1}^n a_i$}`, but this will fail... any idea why? Thanks!!

Comment: @Matifou I think this is due to `soul` not liking `\edef`s in its argument. There might be a workaround but unfortunately I haven't time to think about it right now. You could post a  new question.

Comment: don't worry, thanks for trying!

Comment: @M.Logic You're asking the wrong one. That's Mico.

Comment: What's your real name? I'm sorry that I asked several people but forget who you are.

Answer (score 1):

To change all `\sum` and `\prod` symbols to sans-serif with `unicode-math`, load a sans-serif OpenType math font with `range={\sum,\prod}`.  The Kp fonts are among the few that have a sans math font in the same family, so I use them for this MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont{KpMath-Sans.otf}[range={\sum,\prod}]

\begin{document}
\[ \sum_{i=0}^{N} \prod_{j=1}^{M} ij
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: KPFonts sample]

You might, however, have wanted to use `\sum` and `\sanssum` in the same document (for some reason I don’t understand).  This is possible to do by defining different math versions.  For this MWE, I chose a different default math font whose `\prod` is more obviously different from `\sansprod`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre pagella Math}
\setmathfont{KpMath-Bold.otf}[version=bold]
\setmathfont{KpMath-Sans.otf}[version=sans]

% Based on the definition of \boldsymbol in amsbsy.sty:
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sanssymbol}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@nomath\@gobble \mathversion{sans}%
  \math@atom{#1}{%
  \mathchoice%
    {\hbox{$\m@th\displaystyle#1$}}%
    {\hbox{$\m@th\textstyle#1$}}%
    {\hbox{$\m@th\scriptstyle#1$}}%
    {\hbox{$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle#1$}}}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\newcommand\sanssum{\mathop{\sanssymbol{\sum}}}
\newcommand\sansprod{\mathop{\sanssymbol{\prod}}}

\begin{document}
\[ \sum_{i=0}^{N} \prod_{j=1}^{M} ij \qquad
   \sanssum_{i=0}^{N} \sansprod_{j=1}^{M} ij
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyre Pagella Math / Kp Math Sans sample]

An arguably simpler alternative is to load the sans-serif math font with `\setmathfontface` instead.  You can tweak the `Scale=` of the math font if the automatic scaling doesn’t give you what you want.

With legacy 8-bit font encodings in PDFLaTeX, you would pick a sans-serif math font, load it with `\DeclareSymbolFont`, look up the slots of `\sum` and `\prod` in that font, and then declare the `\sanssum` and `\sansprod` symbols with `\DeclareMathSymbol`.  Unfortunately, nearly every legacy LaTeX math font has a different encoding.

Comment: any chance you would give also an example with `DeclareSymbolFont` as you hint to? That would be very useful, thanks!! :-)

Comment: By the way, could you tell me your real name? I'd like to show thanks to people who help me a lot on LaTeX when writing my book. You can tell me, and then delete it.